# Where does the Mahapp.Metro Dialog buttons get its background color from?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I have copied the ResourceDictionery from [this link here](http://mahapps.com/guides/styles.html#custom) which appears to be the same as an existing Accent.xaml file and changed the accent colors to my own custom colors.

I add my ResourceDictionary in the Application's Resources.

The issue I am seeing is that the background color of a dialog button does not get my custom accent color. If I were to guess it seems to be the Cobalt accent color.

**EDIT Updated Question**   as I wrote above I only added my new Accent Colors to the ResourceDictionary of the Application.  This seems to work for most things but not for the button color of a dialog.  I tested with the Mahapps.Metro samples and found out that if you only add your custom Accent ResourceDictionary to the Applications resources then the background color of a button in the Dialog which should be the AccentColor will not work.  I worked out (and could of read from the instructions :-) ) you need to use the ThemeManager and Override the OnStartUp event.

Now this leads to problem number 2. Here is my code that I have.  The ThemeManger's DetectAppStyle function does not return anything.

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnStartup(e As StartupEventArgs)

        Try
            ThemeManager.AddAccent("NewAccent1", New Uri("pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/NewAccents/NewAccent1.xaml"))

            Dim theme = ThemeManager.DetectAppStyle(Application.Current)

            ThemeManager.ChangeAppStyle(Application.Current, ThemeManager.GetAccent("NewAccent1"), theme.Item1)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.Print(ex.Message)
        End Try

        MyBase.OnStartup(e)
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

MahApps dialog's affirmative button uses `AccentedDialogSquareButton` style which is based on `AccentedSquareButtonStyle`. You can find them in MahApps' source tree as:

- Themes\Dialogs\MessageDialog.xaml
- Themes\Dialogs\BaseMetroDialog.xaml

All other buttons use `SquareButtonStyle` style defined in

- \Styles\Controls.Buttons.xaml

If you want to override this behavior, changes to `BaseMetroDialog.xaml` and `MetroDialog.xaml`(for OK button) are required.

Comment: Thank you Peter I followed that through to find out that it uses the AccentColor color.  This confirmed I had another problem which I have now added to my question above.

Comment: @darbid The Uri looks strange in your sample code. What's your project namespace and where do you put your NewAccent1.xaml?